# changing children of dynamic created states

Tags: apache-flex, dynamic, datagrid, flex3, states

I'm building an Xml-driven application. 
I create new states in a seperate actionscript-class.
These states all contain a DataGrid. 
I can switch the states in the Main.mxml.

But now I would like to access certain children of the DataGrid. In this case I would like to toggle the visibility of GridItems, from a Button in the Main.mxml.

How do I have access and apply this to the already created states ? 
I tried to create RemoveChilds and override/push it to the state.
All I archieved was to remove an entire GridRow at the very last state, but it should be just one GridItem at every state.

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Are you adding the same RemoveChild object to each state? I haven't tried this but if RemoveChild is bound by the same rules as other UI children, adding it to a second state will remove it from the previous one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse your problem. Don't try push the information into the states, have the states fetch the information when needed.

Add a binding in each state to check the status of the button and do the removeChild logic itself.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I definitively have to try your suggestions. I worked it out in my way, but rather complicated I guess:
I push every GridItem in an array when the states are created and create a getFunction which returns the array and so the Main.mxml can access it.
The toggler-function in the Main.mxml looks like this:

```
_gridItemArray = theStateClass.getGridItemArray();

if(_buttonToggler == false)
{
      for each(_gridItemArray.child in _gridItemArray)
  {
    _gridItemArray.child.visible = false;
  }
 _buttonToggler = true;
}

else
{
   for each(_gridItemArray.child in _gridItemArray)
   {
      _gridItemArray.child.visible = true;
   }
       _buttonToggler = false;
    }
```